# Analyse a huge data set of numbers

Tags: java, database, analysis

I am completely new to the topic of big data. I have to analyse a nearly 10 GB text document with numbers. These are nearly 1 billion numbers, so for me it is not so easy to analyse such like this document. The document is structured like a list, one number in one line. My main question is what do you think is the best opportunity to analyse such like these huge data sets? My purpose is to find out how many different numbers the list contains and I want to save this result.

The input is something like this with nearly one billion lines:

> 123801
>   435345
>   123
>   7
>   43958112
>   4569
>   45
>   509858172
>   ...

The output should be like this (just as an example):

> 1 2
>   2 4
>   3 1
>   4 109
>   5 56
>   ...
>   up to nearly one billion

First of all I tried it with linux/unix 'sort' and 'unique' and specific parameters, but for such like this, it is not a solution.

My next thought was try to implement a quick sort or merge sort onto the data set. Is it possible in Java or a different language to analyse/load such like this? I read an ArrayList has least overhead in Java lists. If it is possible I thought I could try to implement a for loop which will increment up to number 'n' and if the nextElement != thisElement go out of the for loop. I think I could save the count with incrementing one variable and set to zero if the condition is correct. What do you think of this idea and of course for this problem?

I also thought about to set up a database for this data set. Is it the better opportunity? And if yes, which DBMS is the best of this?

I am really open minded for anything else and I will really appreciate your opinions, thoughts and solutions!

Comment: your best approach must be to use a buffered writer and increment on a database each number, if you store it on heap it will throw an Exception.

Comment: Maybe you should first be more precise how the input is structured, because you wrote "one number in one line." but in the exmaple you show two numbers per line. What do you what to count? How many unique lines in the file or the number of occurence per number?

Comment: Sorry, this should be the output of it, not the input file. Edited it above.

Comment: Are you trying to do a frequency count of each number?

Comment: Perhaps something like SAX can handle this, as it is capable of streaming the text, rather than loading it all into memory.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done in parallel if you follow something like this pattern:

1) split the file into manageable chunks (you'd need to use "split -l" to split at a line boundary so rather than an absolute size in MB choose an appropriate number of lines)

2) analyse each chunk, an "awk" (gawk) script could do this effectively, as the file size is not too big the memory requirement will be reasonable;  Write these intermediate results to a separate file for each chunk.

3) merge the results of all the analyses - but this would still require too much memory;
Perhaps if your script merged only selected rages of numbers from across all chunks i.e. numbers 0..1000000, 200000..3000000, and so on;  these results will be definitive for each range.  A preliminary analysis of the first couple of chunks might give you an idea of the distibution of values and where to set these boundaries.

4) Finally merge those results into one file

I suggest standard shell utilities here because they are well suited to text processing and it could be done that way, but most languages should be able to cope.

Depending on how big the largest number is you may need to use BigInteger in Java for example;  On the other hand "awk" simply treats them as text so it's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

10GB numbers in file = ~5-50 GB in memory

The problem is that you CANT load all your data and then "unique" them, cause JVM or even your computer cant handle that much GB in RAM.

Because it is not possible to just load some input, count sub-result and add to a result (like adding all numbers), the best approach is to send these numbers to database with UNIQUE modifier. A lot smart people worked a lot hours on databases to make them as fast as possible, so it will be much faster than any of your "local" solution.

The databases itselft... every world-wide database is usefull, each one is good or bad in something. For example facebook and youtube runs on MySQL - so even MySQL is used for huge systems.

Comment: You don't need to load the raw data into memory. You only need to keep the counts in memory. Assuming 1 billion unique keys: 1 billion * (4 bytes key + 4 bytes count) = 8 GB. Add some waste from the hash table, 16 GB. Definitely would fit in my ram, unless I use inefficient data structures (in Java, use GNU Trove `TIntIntHashMap`)

Answer (score 0):

The core data structure to use is Map(Integer,Integer) to store counters of occurrences for each number.

If you have a machine with several dozens GB RAM, you can try to use ordinary java.util.hashMap.

Otherwise, you can use any database - each DBMS can manage such tables. For simplicity, use an embedded one.

To achieve best speed, however, you can write specialized program, which resembles external sorting, but which replaces series of identical numbers with pair [number, counter]. It may work as follows:

- read input file and collect  pairs in a TreeMap until memory is available.
- save TreeMap in a binary file as sorted sequence of pairs
- clear TreeMap and continue until the end of input file
- merge saved files

Answer (score 0):

I believe they want you to arrive at **probabilistic counting** at some point. See for example: [Big Data Counting: How To Count A Billion Distinct Objects Using Only 1.5KB Of Memory](http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/4/5/big-data-counting-how-to-count-a-billion-distinct-objects-us.html)

If you want *exact* counts, **sort** the data (use TeraSort, if you have really large sets) and then just count how many times the exact same value occurs next to each other.

Or use MapReduce. Map each number to (number, 1), and then sum the second column in the reducer.

If you want to do it manually, `sort` can also perform merges. So you can use `split` to partition your data, `sort` each partition, then `sort -m` the partitions and `uniq -c` count the results. If you want to do it in Java: **never use Java Collections with primitive types**. That wastes tons of memory. Use GNU Trove types such as `TIntIntHashMap`.

```
# Split into chunks of 100k lines:
split -l100000 input temp-
# Sort each chunk
for nam in temp-*; do sort $nam > sorted-$nam; done
# Merge-sort and count:
sort -m sorted-* | uniq -c
```